# "Move or throw" using the ternary operator

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Since C++11 I have been using the ternary operator to move or throw based on some condition, but with latest GCC (9.1 and trunk) is not working anymore.

I have reduced the problem to this example ([Wandbox permalink](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4RG80Oqnurz9ad9w)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() 
{
    auto p = std::make_unique<int>();
    std::cout << "p.get(): " << p.get() << std::endl;

    {
        std::cout << "Move p into q" << std::endl;
        auto q = p ? std::move(p) : throw std::invalid_argument{"null ptr"};

        std::cout << "q.get(): " << q.get() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "p.get(): " << p.get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It works with GCC 8.3 and older, and with every Clang version; and `p` is moved:

```
p.get(): 0xde5c20
Move p into q
q.get(): 0xde5c20
p.get(): 0
```

But now with GCC 9.1 and later it doesn't work:

```
p.get(): 0x1d89150
Move p into q
q.get(): 0x1d89150
p.get(): 0x1d89150
```

And then the program crashes due to a double free.

Is this a bug in GCC 9.1/trunk? Or latest GCC is the only one doing the right thing and this is not valid C++?

Comment: Probably related to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90393

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *has* to be a bug.

Either the move will be a move or the compilation should fail due to attempted copy of a `unique_ptr` (or a `throw` occurs in which case it doesn't matter).

`q.get() == p.get()` indeed shows that the internals have broken down, as this should not be possible.

I'd agree with cpplearner that this is [bug 90393](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90393) (and all its dupes), which is reported as having been introduced in GCC 9.1.

Either downgrade, wait to upgrade, or reform your code into a nice `if`/`else`.